# No cashew visible on desktop of Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: kubuntu

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.  The cashew is not visible on the desktop.  I don't know what I did to make it disappear. Nevertheless, how can I get it back?

Comment: Keep track of what you do, at least long enough to ask "did that do what I expected?".

Comment: I too wish to know of this mystery nut.

Comment: Open a shell....

Comment: There are lots of references to the "cashew" in the KDE documention. It's a menu that gets activated when you click on the upper right corner of the screen -- sometimes.  I agree -- it's a mystifying entity.

Comment: I think it's gone away, but the fact that there are so many reference to it in KDE documentation is very troublesome.  If you search for the solution of some KDE problem, you're likely to find that the solution involves the cashew.

Comment: From reading another comment, there's [this](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/10/kde-kills-desktop-toolbox-icon). I had no idea that was considered a cashew.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on desktop,chose Configure Desktop,chose Tweaks,check "Show the desktop toolbox".